# Export CSV file from order grid

Tags: csv, sales-order, export

I wanna export CSV from sales -> orders grid with only selected lines and not all commands like with the default button.

If there's a solution for that ?

Thank you for advance

Comment: can you put your demo csv

Comment: I only wanna export the orders grid but only with the selected commands (with the 1st column) and not all commands like the default export button

Answer (score 1):

So what happens when the order csv is run is the following.

1. The action `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController::exportCsvAction` is called,
2. This creates a grid block with `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_order_grid');`,
3. This grid is then used to fill the csv in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_exportIterateCollection`

What you could do is rewrite the admin controller or make your own controller and then use this in the admin section. Then instead of simply getting a complete sales order grid you can build the grid with the correct collection including the filters selected by the user.

Comment: Suppose we use the normal CSV Export action as an example? HOw could we then export by `  $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());` : export $orderIds only from collection?